# Как указать размеры картинок в коде JavaScript? (код в основной части)

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var a=Math.round(Math.random()*3)
image = new Array();
linked=new Array();
linked[0]="../notes/1.php"
linked[1]="../notes/2.php"
linked[2]="../notes/3.php"
linked[3]="../notes/4.php"
image[0]="../images/notes/one.jpg"
image[1]="../images/notes/two.jpg"
image[2]="../images/notes/three.jpg"
image[3]="../images/notes/four.jpg"
document.write ("<a href="+linked[a]+"><img src="+image[a]+"></a>");
</script>
```

Comment: Вопросы надо править, если закрыли, а  не плодить одинаковые...

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете задать размеры, например так:

```
document.write ("<a href="+linked[a]+"><img style='width: 150px; height: 100px' src="+image[a]+"></a>");
```

Или же, на подобии как это делаете Вы:

```
size[0]={width: '100px', heigth: '150px'}
size[1]={width: '100px', heigth: '150px'}
size[2]={width: '100px', heigth: '150px'}
size[3]={width: '100px', heigth: '150px'}
document.write (`<a href=${linked[a]}><img style=width:${size[dd].width};height:${size[a].heigth} src=${image[a]}></a>`)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Здесь,  "спасибо",  принято выражать принятием вопроса ("галочка" с левой стороны) и отметкой , что ответ был полезен (стрелка "вверх")